# How to build android health application via free open source commuity

Tags: android

We are looking to build a platform on the Android health and health website, which is similar to the examples of [Lybrate](http://www.lybrate.com/) or [Medshr](https://en.medshr.net). It's actually an environment like the Instagram app with some features like:

- Video and audio calls
   -Ranking
  -View and connect to other sites such as Isentagram, Watts App
- Medical consultation and time
  Multi-choice medical tests for diagnosis
  -To advise between groups of physicians for better diagnosis
  Location of physician and patient
  -To store patient medical information in the system in the form of a photo, video or text.
- Collaboration with insurance to facilitate drug delivery
- Automatic posting of the medication after the patient's visit to the patient's address for the big cities
  -To work with private medical and government organizations for retraining - pursuing complaints and ...
- Ability to train through video, audio, and text video and audio tests and register sample cases for medical and health students.
- To cooperate to improve charity by introducing people in need and cases to the state agencies or charities or physicians and individuals.
  And...

Needs of this project is big and more.

1- So could we describe free open source subject for our project?

2-What kind of rules and ... Needed to attract and manage new people around the world to work together?

3-Do you know any successfull experiment of this kind in android application building field as free open source communuty?

4-Any ... Yours suggestion for doing better work?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very big question.

Before anything else, you should think more concretely about what you're planning on doing.  Both the Lybrate and Medshr apps are zero-cost; if you're going to develop a fully-free competitor app that uses your proprietary back-end, that's great, but the group of people who care about freedom as opposed to cost in their phone apps is fairly small compared to the market as a whole.  If you're planning on freeing both the user app *and* the back-end, that's fantastic, but it's going to be very hard to make a business plan that's attractive to funding.

What you're planning to do has some serious privacy implications.  Even the US, which is generally pretty *laissez-faire* about privacy, [gets all steamed up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Insurance_Portability_and_Accountability_Act) about protecting healthcare information.  If you release code to do some of the things you list which turns out to have holes in it that let people get hold of other people's information, you could end up facing *substantial* fines, or even going to jail.  It also seems to be quite country-specific.

That given, I think you have two ways to go.  You can get a working business plan together, get a big chunk of funding somehow, and pay lots of developers to implement it all.  That doesn't stop you releasing the whole thing open-source, but expect a lot of pushback from your investors.

Alternatively, you can drastically reduce the scope of what you're doing (less tasks, for less people, in a smaller location) in order to be able to get something that people can download off [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org) that *actually works*.  One of the best ways to get volunteers to help code is to give them something that solves a problem they have, but which could solve it even better if it were just fixed up a little.  Your question about rules needed to attract and manage volunteers from around the world is premature: should you be lucky enough to have more volunteers than you can handle, and I emphasise that this is not the usual problem, you can get started with community managers and codes of conduct at that time.

Comment: Thank a lot, we have not any sponser still, but i am searching via internet by some tag like volunteering and ... To find out the proper way. Appritiateing for any suggestion.

Comment: @user296115 you're very welcome.  At some point (preferably when you've got an answer you're happy with) you should accept an answer to this question, by clicking the "tick" outline next to it, otherwise it will float around forever like a grumpy albatross.  My apologies if you already know this.